# Set a key in RDD

Tags: key, pyspark, rdd

I have a RDD of list or np.arrays like this one:

```
[([1,0,0])
 ([0,1,0])
 ([0,0,1])]
```

Is it possible to set a different key to every line in this RDD? The numbers are the best example:

```
[(0, [1,0,0])
 (1, [0,1,0])
 (2, [0,0,1])]
```

My first attempt is:

```
rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda line: (key, line))
```

How I can set the *different and unique* keys in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zipWithIndex`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

rdd.zipWithIndex().map(itemgetter(1, 0))
```

or `zipWithUniqueId`:

```py
rdd.zipWithUniqueId().map(itemgetter(1, 0))
```

The former one requires additional action but it is deterministic.